# How do I include a library in C++ that had been built from source code? [LINUX]

Tags: c++, build, include, static-libraries, mlpack

I have cloned a C++ library repo called 'mlpack'. I built the library using cmake and now I want to include it to my C++ file. I am using ubuntu 19.04. I tried to run the command:

```
g++ -std=c++11 test.cpp -I/home/koushik/Documents/'Git Repo'/mlpack/build/lib -lmlpack -larmadillo -lboost_serialization -fopenmp
```

Here `/home/koushik/Documents/'Git Repo'/mlpack/build/lib` is the build directory of the library. I tried this command thinking it would look for includes in that build directory. But I get the error:

```
test.cpp:1:10: fatal error: mlpack/core.hpp: No such file or directory
 #include <mlpack/core.hpp>
          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
```

when I try to include the library and compile code.

Apart from the above coommand I also tried

```
$ export LD_LIBRARY_PATH='/home/koushik/Documents/Git Repo/mlpack/build/lib'
$ g++ -std=c++11 test.cpp -lmlpack -larmadillo -lboost_serialization -fopenmp
```

This failed as well giving the same error as above.

I would like to clarify that I have all the other linked libraries installed via apt and they work fine when linked in other C++ files. Only mlpack is built from source and I am trying to include.

Comment: `-I` is for header files (`.hpp`), not for libraries.

Comment: You say you "built the library using cmake", but did you install it as well? if you did, did you specify a `CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX` when you ran cmake, or is it installed in the system?

Comment: No I didn't install it. I didn't use the command 'cmake install' rather I used 'cmake' command. I didn't install because I want to make changes to the library and rebuild many times. @Frank

Answer (score 1):

Using a library from its cmake binary directory is generally a bad idea, and often straight up doesn't work.

What you want to do is choose a location on your machine where you want to install the library and its headers. Then you do:

```
mkdir lib_build
cd lib_build
cmake -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/path/to/install/dir path/to/lib/source
make && make install
```

This will generally create `include` and `lib` directories (and sometimes a few more, like `bin` or `share`) at the specified location containing the public-facing build of the project.

When you make changes to the library, you can re-run `make && make install` to update the installation.

Then, when building something that depends on the library, you would typically do:

```
g++ -I/path/to/install/dir/include -L/path/to/install/dir/lib ...
```